# Calculate mean of weather station data in r

Tags: r

I am working with a dataset of about 800 weather stations, with monthly air temperature values for each station from 1986 to 2014. The data are split into three columns: (1) station name, (2) date (year and month), and (3) Temp. In general, the data look something like this:

```
STATION    DATE    TEMP
Station 1  198601  -15
Station 1  198602  -16
Station 1  201401  -10
Station 1  201402  -14
Station 2  198601  -11
Station 2  198602  -9
Station 2  201401  -5
Station 2  201402  -4
```

I need to extract the average temperature at each weather station for a given month in various year ranges. For example, if I needed to know the average July temperature at each weather station from 1986-1990. My ideal output, then would be a new list or dataframe giving the average temperature for each station, based on my specified date range.

I am sure this can be accomplished using a for loop, but I am not very proficient at creating such code. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Using dplyr instead of data table

```
weather <- data.frame(station = c("Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 1", "Station 1",
                              "Station 2", "Station 2", "Station 2", "Station 2"),
                  date = c(198601, 198602, 201401, 201402, 198601, 198602, 201401, 201402),
                  temp = c(-15, -16, -10, -14, -11, -9, -5, -4))


library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
# get month and year columns in data
weather <- mutate(weather,
              year = str_extract(date, "\\d{4}"),
              month = str_extract(date, "\\d{2}$"))

# get the mean for each station for each month
mean_station <- group_by(weather, station, month) %>%
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temp, na.rm = T))
```

If you need to only do this on a certain range of dates you can add a filter on the year

```
mean_station <- group_by(weather, station, month) %>%
  filter(year >= 1986, year <= 2015) %>%
  summarise(mean_temp = mean(temp, na.rm = T))
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...?

```
> df$month <- substr(df$DATE, 5, 6)
> result <- aggregate(TEMP~STATION+month, mean, data=df)
> data.frame(Year=unique(substr(df$DATE, 1, 4)), result)
  Year  STATION month  TEMP
1 1986 Station1    01 -12.5
2 2014 Station2    01  -8.0
3 1986 Station1    02 -15.0
4 2014 Station2    02  -6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

Or maybe

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, list(MeanTemp = mean(TEMP)), 
                by = list(STATION, Mon = substr(DATE, 5, 6))]

#      STATION Mon MeanTemp
# 1: Station 1  01    -12.5
# 2: Station 1  02    -15.0
# 3: Station 2  01     -8.0
# 4: Station 2  02     -6.5
```

Answer (score 1):

I am also learning R and may not answer your question directly but I wanted to mention that seas Package is helpful for analysis of such type of data

for example

```
require(seas)
pdf( paste("test",".pdf", sep="") )  
for (i in 1: length(STATION)){
d1 <-mksub(mdata,id=STATION[i]) # making a subset for each station based on name/unique id
dat.ss <- seas.sum(d1)
plot(dat.ss)  
}    
graphics off ()
```

You have to ensure that str() of your dataset is the in format that seas needs.
with such large dataset I am advise loops and functions helps with data analysis a bit quickly. If got another way of looping that works grateful if you can share